# Is CiviCRM 4.6 Bootstrap Compatible

Tags: ui

On a 4.5 site running the most recent Drupal, I have to use the themekey module to make CiviCRM public facing pages use a different theme from the site default because of Bootstrap compatibility problems. (For admin stuff I'm using a non-bootstrap admin theme.)

The client really wants the public-facing part of the site to use the same bootstrap theme for all pages.

Is 4.6 have any better Bootstrap compatibility than 4.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4.7 should be, but not 4.6 as is. There was a [GSoC student who worked on making CiviCRM more Bootstrap-friendly](https://github.com/amilineni/civicrm-core/commits/master), unfortunately the patches were not merged in for 4.6.

I've started working on it again, based on Amilineni's work, but I'm slowly moving forward. If anyone beats me to it, I will be more than happy :)

So far, I've been trying to add a few classes to core forms (CRM/Core/Form.php), and try to see if we can override the CSS on buttons using Saas/Less, and perhaps moving a bit of CSS out of civicrm.css so that we can make it optional (to avoid loading extra CSS rules if we are using Bootstrap).

Comment: Would you mind lending a hand with information about why 4.7 should be more Bootstrap friendly? Thanks.